# Correct Way to do Routing with ID in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am learning AngularJS . Now I am confuse in routing with AngularJS . Actually I need at my main page that Task is created.http://localhost:8080/#/ .So this url is for creation of Task .Now if user wants to edit the task then I append the id in routeParams http://localhost:8080/#/5 in this way . Now if user wants to see allTask then the URL is http://localhost:8080/#/allTask . But it takes allTask as a id and go to edit task URL . routing for this is

```
'use strict';

angular.module("mainApp",['ngRoute','ngResource','ngGrid','ui.codemirror']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'component/task/Task.html',
    controller: 'taskController'
    })
    .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'component/task/Task.html',
    controller: 'taskController'
    })

    .when('/allTask', {
        templateUrl: 'component/allTask/allTask.html',
        controller: 'allTaskController'
    })  
}])
```

Comment: no offense, but this is kinda bad routing. If you have a task, then your router should probably use .when("/task/:id?") to route to the proper controller.  The question mark at the end marks it as an optional parameter. So this isn't really an issue that angular has, it's an issue with the route names you use.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `allTask` route before the one with `:id`, like this:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngGrid', 'ui.codemirror']).
config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/allTask', {
        templateUrl: 'component/allTask/allTask.html',
        controller: 'allTaskController'
      })
      .when('/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'component/task/Task.html',
        controller: 'taskController'
      })
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'component/task/Task.html',
        controller: 'taskController'
      });
  }
])
```

Also you can have one route instead of the latter two, by making the parameter `:id` optional (with question mark `?`). Here is the updated code:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngGrid', 'ui.codemirror']).
config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/allTask', {
        templateUrl: 'component/allTask/allTask.html',
        controller: 'allTaskController'
      })
      .when('/:id?', {
        templateUrl: 'component/task/Task.html',
        controller: 'taskController'
      });
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks it works but it is the correct way or Angular have any better way to handle this type of problem

Comment: @abhaygarg12493, this isn't really a problem with Angular, this is a problem with route names, you need more descriptive routes. The "index" page should be a default page the user sees which doesn't require any parameters.